# Ember.js wysiwyg inline editor

Tags: ember.js, wysiwyg

I've been looking for a small, fast, inline editor for quite a while. The new ckeditor looks like an alternative, but it is still too much. All I would need is inline formating, image handling.

Doew anyone know a wysiwyg editor which works perfectly with Ember.js? (I know, all do, but I really mean work great together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps than playing with the new HTML5 contenteditable tag?

Or start coding and implement something yourself like [Create.js](http://createjs.org/) but using ember instead of underscore.

Answer (score 3):

I just did a post on using Summernote with Ember.js that you can see here http://hbrysiewicz.github.io/2014-04-18-summernote-ember-wysiwyg.html

Comment: I might be a surprise, but I already read it :) Also, I am planning to give your solution a spin soon.

Comment: Can you please guide me as per http://hbrysiewicz.com/2014-04-18-summernote-ember-wysiwyg.html#comment-3332843039. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this is an option:

[bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) for [ember](https://github.com/pjlammertyn/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/packages/ember-bootstrap/lib/views/wysihtml5.js)

Comment: It looks ok, only it is not inline.

Comment: Perhaps than playing with the new HTML5 [contenteditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) tag? Or start coding and implement something yourself like [Create.js](http://createjs.org/) but using ember instead of underscore.

Comment: Implementing something similar to create.js is a good idea, thx!

Comment: Maybe you should add this as a answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Another good option is a [jQuery plugin called editable](http://plugins.jquery.com/editable/). I am using it in my project and it seems to play nicely with Ember -- so far no issues.

Comment: I haven`t checked the code of this plugin, but it looks like it does exactly what the contenteditable property does. And you don`t need any js for that. On the other hand, contenteditable and ember kind of need to be `hacked` together. This is why I am looking for a finished solution. Also, this plugin misses wysiwyg editor features.

Comment: I almost assumed the same thing, but decided to give it a try. I can tell you that at least in my app I didn't have to do any hacks to make `editable()` work. However, before that I had tried using `contenteditable` and as you say it was not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

[TinyEditor](https://github.com/woody180/tinyeditor) is a cool solution for inline editing. It's basically a tinyMCE editor with elFinder file manager encapsulated in only one - tinyeditor.js file.

Answer (score -1):

Pure ember.js WYSIWYG component: http://indexiatech.github.io/ember-components/#/component/component.wysiwyg/simple